# Convert nested list of lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have an array of lists that I need to turn into a dictionary where the first element in each list is a key and the remaining elements are values corresponding to that key.

For example, the array:

```
 a=[[[1, 2, 4] [2, 1, 3, 5] [3, 2, 6]]
   [[4, 1, 5, 7] [5, 2, 4, 6, 8] [6, 3, 5, 9]]]
```

should look like:

```
 dict = {1:[2,4], 2:[1,3,5], 3:[2,6], 4:[1,5,7], 5:[2,4,6,8], 6:[3,5,9]}
```

While the object looks like a list of lists, it is actually an array created by this process:

```
 a = [[i] for i in range(1, 10)]
     swap = a[0]
     a[0] = None
     b = np.array(a)
     b[0] = swap
     b.shape = 3, 3
```

Then I looped through the array and appended numbers to the different list elements which is why the lists have expanded. Let me know if that's not clear!

Is there an easy way to loop through an array and create this? Thanks!

Comment: @kawadhiya21 How are you so sure? _Technically_ that is a list of lists. _Technically_ it's not an array of anything.

Comment: Execute the statement in question. It will throw exception.

Comment: Yeah you're right, the OP is missing a comma. I'll correct it.

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi. It's not clear how deeply nested those lists are. I think you should wait for the OP to correct it.

Comment: @ekhumoro I was incorrect because the OP was missing a comma. But it is negligence to simply assume the OP's "deep nesting" is incorrect when that could in fact be the data structure they're working in ;)

Comment: The question is still not clear. Neither `a` nor `b` looks like the original example. Please edit your question and add a [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

You can use nested dict comprehension with [*extended iterable unpacking*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
>>> l = [[[1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 3, 5], [3, 2, 6]], [[4, 1, 5, 7], [5, 2, 4, 6, 8], [6, 3, 5, 9]]]
>>> {k: v for sub_l in l for k, *v in sub_l}
{1: [2, 4], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [2, 6], 4: [1, 5, 7], 5: [2, 4, 6, 8], 6: [3, 5, 9]}
```

Comment: This is a great solution ! There's always something to learn here on stackoverflow. Thanks @niemmi

Comment: Sweet, I had a similar but slightly different problem, and I could adapt this solution to fit it well. Thanks! This is really cool syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Using generator to flatten the list,

```
a=[
     [[1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 3, 5], [3, 2, 6], ],
     [[4, 1, 5, 7], [5, 2, 4, 6, 8], [6, 3, 5, 9]],

   ]

def flat(a):
    for level1 in a:
        for level2 in level1:
            yield level2

result = {}
for l in flat(a):
    result[l[0]] = l[1:]

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution based on @niemmi answer using [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) maybe more readable:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [[[1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 3, 5], [3, 2, 6]], [[4, 1, 5, 7], [5, 2, 4, 6, 8], [6, 3, 5, 9]]]
>>> {k: v for k, *v in itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)}
{1: [2, 4], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [2, 6], 4: [1, 5, 7], 5: [2, 4, 6, 8], 6: [3, 5, 9]}
```

Now we got only one `for` loop by flatten the `l` list.